# Linq Error Service Broker message delivery is not enabled in this database

Tags: c#, sql, linq

We have C# LINQ program that writes/reads to a database. We recently moved the database to a different server. I changed the app.config to point to this new server and since then i am getting this error when I do a write to a table. specifically the error occurs on db.SubmitChanges()

"Service Broker message delivery is not enabled in this database. Use the ALTER DATABASE statement to enable Service Broker message delivery."

The same program works fine in the other server with Service Broker message delivery disabled and this is a simple insert into a table. I tried inserting into another test table and that works fine. I can't seem to find a pattern as to when the error occurs either.

Comment: Do you get any messages when you try to enable the service broker on the new database location?

Comment: No. DBA hasn't enabled it because it wasn't required in the current database. Its going to be a while before that get's done !

Answer (score 0):

You probably already know this stuff from the comment you exchanged with Gert. But...

There is a database option that switches on or off the service broker mechanism.

From mater database, you can check what the settings is on your database (in the same instance)

```sql
USE master;

-- Check if it is enabled
SELECT D.is_broker_enabled
FROM sys.databases D
WHERE D.name = 'YourDatabaseName' ;

-- Enable it
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName
  SET ENABLE_BROKER
  WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ;

GO
```

I usually add this to the beginning of the service broker application setup script

```sql
USE master;

IF NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT D.is_broker_enabled
  FROM sys.databases D
  WHERE
    D.name = 'YourDatabaseName'
    AND D.is_broker_enabled = 1
)
  ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName
     SET ENABLE_BROKER
     WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ;

GO
```

So I can make sure it gets enabled.  But you probably should talk to your DBA because service broker probably eats up some resource in DB engine just by enabling it.